# See the expansion of Bash variables for debugging?

Tags: bash, variable, variable-substitution

Is there any tools/tricks available for expanding variables to make bash code easier to read?

For example it would convert the following:

```
DIR=/var/tmp
FILE=${DIR}/file
SCRIPT_ROOT=/opt/root
TOOL=${SCRIPT_ROOT}/tool.sh
${TOOL} ${FILE}
```

to:

```
DIR=/var/tmp
FILE=/var/tmp/file
SCRIPT_ROOT=/opt/root
TOOL=/opt/root/tool.sh
/opt/root/tool.sh /var/tmp/file
```

- I'm converting BASH code to Python and reading BASH syntax is helllla-tedious.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Run the script under `bash -x`:

```
$ bash -x script
+ DIR=/var/tmp
+ FILE=/var/tmp/file
+ SCRIPT_ROOT=/opt/root
+ TOOL=/opt/root/tool.sh
+ /opt/root/tool.sh /var/tmp/file
```

While `-x` is normally used for debugging, it seems to meet your needs.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> -x         Print commands and their arguments as they are executed.